# symfony2 how to get mapping table id?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

how to get mapping table id from mappipng table?

i have user and group table mapped together 
and i want to get group id at login time but i am not getting it.

i have three table 
**user,  group,  user_groupname**

->first table

**user**

id,name

->second table

**group**

id,name

->third table

**groupname**

user_id,group_id

first entity is as follows

```
/Entity/groupname.php

class groupname
{


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="role", inversedBy="groupname")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="groupname_role",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="groupname_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Dashboard\SecurityBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="groupname")
     */
    private $users;

}
```

second entity is as follows

```
/Entity/User.php
<?php

namespace Dashboard\SecurityBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Dashboard\SecurityBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Dashboard\SecurityBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable, AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

    */

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Dashboard\AdminManageUserBundle\Entity\groupname", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    public $groupname;  

    /**
     * @var Dashboard\SecurityBundle\Entity\UserPhoto UserPhoto
     *
     */
    private $userPhoto;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groupname    = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    /**
     * Add groupname
     *
     * @param \Dashboard\AdminManageUserBundle\Entity\groupname $groupname
     * @return User
     */
    public function addGroupname(\Dashboard\AdminManageUserBundle\Entity\groupname $groupname)
    {
        $this->groupname[] = $groupname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove groupname
     *
     * @param \Dashboard\AdminManageUserBundle\Entity\groupname $groupname
     */
    public function removeGroupname(\Dashboard\AdminManageUserBundle\Entity\groupname $groupname)
    {
        $this->groupname->removeElement($groupname);
    }

    /**
     * Get groupname
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection 
     */
    public function getGroupname()
    {

        return $this->groupname;
    }
}
```

and i have following code right in Controller file

```
$userEntity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DashboardSecurityBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('username' =>$usernames));
```

and i have `print_R($userEntity)` pc got hanged

Answer (score 0):

$userEntiry is a object of **UserEntity**

So, your pc got hanged.

please try this.

```
   print_r($userEntity->getUsername());
```

Comment: i have allready try this   print_r($userEntity->getUsername());  but firefox  hanged  
and not get my group name id